# slide vertices around a face

Tags: edit-mode

i think i saw in a video once, someone took a loop of vertices from one mesh, copied it, and applied it to another mesh in a way that it perfectly snapped to the surface of the other mesh. no matter where he put it, the loop flowed across the surface of the other mesh perfectly. [image: a loop of vertices flowing across a form]

am i dreaming this or is this possible.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation well, can you expand the question?

Comment: Is it something like this? https://youtu.be/luFz5gzvM9s